# Install UniversalMediaServer on Linux Mint 19.1

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, multimedia

How do I install 
UniversalMediaServer on Mint? The [instructions](https://github.com/UniversalMediaServer/UniversalMediaServer/blob/master/INSTALL.txt) are somewhat unspecific and long not tested, do I have to take care of certain specialties on Mint?

Or should I use the [instructions for Ubuntu 16](https://www.slsmk.com/how-to-install-universal-media-server-ums-on-ubuntu-in-headless-mode/)?

Comment: Is trying it out of the question?

Comment: I will try it out and post a complete instruction here if I succeed....

Comment: The instructions *are* specific, but they appear geared towards Ubuntu (12!); since Mint is a Debian/Ubuntu distribution, it's *possible* that the instructions will work. I'd recommend entering them (or whatever you think the most recent versions would be) and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

First you must have Java 8 JRE installed on the server. OpenJava will not work.

```
apt-get install software-properties-common
apt-get update
apt-get install openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

With Java installed, we now need to add some other pre-reqs:

```
apt-get install mediainfo dcraw vlc-nox mplayer mencoder
```

use the `/opt` directory for the install. Then download the latest UMS package from [fosshub](https://www.fosshub.com/Universal-Media-Server.html). After the download is complete, unpack the file with tar. I create a softlink using `/opt/ums` so that when we need to upgrade, we can just point the softlink to the new directory while not touching the config files that we will be using in a systemd startscript.

```
VERSION=8.0.1
cd /opt
wget https://www.fosshub.com/Universal-Media-Server.html?dwl=UMS-$VERSION.tgz
tar -xvzf UMS-*
ln -s /opt/ums-$VERSION ums
```

Now you can run UMS with

```
 cd /opt/ums/
 ./UMS.sh
```

Or you install a systemd service to controll UMS, like for example here: https://nerdpause.de/ums-als-systemd-service/